# Display the number of replies to a message with inner joins in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Anything beyond basic SQL statements, not my strong point.

I have a messaging system that I'm coding that is kind of like facebook's where instead of separate messages, you reply to one main message, and all the messages you're participating in are displayed in one spot.

mail table:

- mailID
- mailUser: person that sent the message
- mailTo
- mailUnread: 1 is unread
- mailSubject
- mailBody
- mailCurrency
- mailTime
- mailDeleted: 1 is deleted

relevant fields in the  mailreply table:

- mailreplyID
- mailreplyUser: user that's replying
- mailreplyDeleted: 1 is deleted
- mailreplyTo: the id of the message that is replied to

Original I coded it so that it didn't count the number of replies and that worked fine, but I decided it would be helpful to include the number.

This is what I originally had:

```
SELECT 
    a.mailID, 
    a.mailUser, 
    a.mailTo, 
    b.username AS usernamea, 
    c.username AS usernameb
FROM 
    mail a, users b, users c 
WHERE 
    (a.mailUser = b.id OR a.mailUser = c.id) 
    AND (a.mailTo = '".$id."' OR a.mailUser = '".$id."') 
    AND a.mailDeleted = '0'
GROUP BY a.mailID
ORDER BY a.mailID DESC
```

This was my attempt:

```
SELECT
    a.mailID, 
    a.mailUser, 
    a.mailTo, 
    b.username AS usernamea, 
    c.username AS usernameb
FROM 
    mail a, users b, users c
    LEFT JOIN mailreply d 
    ON d.mailreplyTo = a.mailID
WHERE 
    (a.mailUser = b.id OR a.mailUser = c.id) 
    AND (a.mailTo = '".$id."' OR a.mailUser = '".$id."') 
    AND a.mailDeleted = '0'
GROUP BY a.mailID
ORDER BY a.mailID DESC
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi Rebecca, Welcome to Stack Oveflow!  Did your second attempt work?  Did you get any errors or unexpected results?

Comment: Sadly no. I get a "supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource" error. I'm not sure what the problem is and I keep trying to change things around with no luck.

Comment: I took the liberty of removing any columns from your query that didn't look like they were important for solving this problem, I hope you don't mind...you should be able to just add them back in once we've figured this out.  Also, the error you mentioned sounds like it's a PHP error...did you get any errors from MySQL itself?

Comment: Thanks! It's fine.

I just assumed there's a problem with the SQL since the problem only happens when I change it away from what I originally had. The line the error is from is from a mysql_num_rows.

Comment: The mysql_* functions require the parameter to be a "MySQL resource" which is essentially what you get from a mysql_* function call that succeeds. Your error would indicate that whatever you're doing isn't working, or is causing an SQL error. Please try using [mysql_error](http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) to find out what the SQL error is. - Also, did you consider using a single table for all this? You could just store data in mailreply in your main mail table.

Comment: @Rebecca, could you try getting the MySQL error message with the [mysql_error function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) please?

Comment: Also rather than supplying just the sql could you please provided me with the php thats calling this query. I have you tried this query in PhpMyadmin or sqlpro or something, i find it often useful to test the sql im writing

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    a.mailID, 
    a.mailUser, 
    a.mailTo, 
    b.username AS fromUsername, 
    c.username AS toUsername,
    count(d.mailReplyID) as mailCount
FROM 
    mail a
    INNER JOIN users b ON b.id=a.mailUserId
    INNER JOIN users c ON c.id=a.mailTo
    LEFT JOIN mailreply d 
    ON d.mailreplyTo = a.mailID
WHERE 
   (a.mailTo = '".$id."' OR a.mailUser = '".$id."') 
    AND a.mailDeleted = '0'
GROUP BY a.mailID
ORDER BY a.mailID DESC
```

You need to join to the users table on each side of the message to get the usernames. I think you were confusing the where clause to check if the current user is sender or recipient with the join specification, that's a good reason for using the INNER JOIN syntax rather than separating tables by commas and putting the join spec in the where clause.

You then group by the mail ID as you correctly did, and add in a count column on the mailreply table. As this table is left joined, which you were also right about, it will also return the messages with a count of zero replies.

Hope that sorts it for you - you were nearly there!

James